# Understanding the notations used to denote vector

Tags: matrices, vectors

In my research work I usually came across the following notations of vector.

$\mathbf{g} = [g_{1},...,g_{N}]^T$ ---(1)

$\mathbf{g}^T = [g_{1},...,g_{N}]$ ---(2)

As per my understanding, I am sure that the $\mathbf{g}$ in eq. (1) is column vector.

My query is $\mathbf{g}$ in eq. (2) will it be a column vector or row vector ?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated

Comment: When you transpose twice what do you get?

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your hint ... I got the correct way of dealing with such notations. So here $\mathbf{g}$ in eq. (2) will also be a column vector.

Comment: Absolutely. $\phantom.$